# In the dataframe here, how to replace Jen's gpa 3.8 with 3.2? I can replace all 3.8s with 3.2, but how to replace only Jen's 3.8?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is what I have for the dataset:
[image: dataframe]

Here is how I replace all 3.8 with 3.2. But how to replace only Jen's 3.8?
[image: how to replace only Jen's 3.8 to 3.2?]

I can replace all 3.8s with 3.2. But how to replace only Jen's 3.8 with 3.2? I guess one way is to use iloc. Any different versions of the solutions? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not filter specifically to Jen and replace the GPA?

```
df = df.loc[df['name'] == 'Jen', 'gpa'] = 3.2
```

Comment: It does not work.  I tried the following but still doesn't; work. students_df.iloc['name']==students_df['Jen'].replace(["3.8"],3.2)

Comment: I don't understand how that would not work unless `name` is an index. What exactly about it does not work?